# Beamer: Vertical shading + plain frame leaves white strip at top of page

Tags: beamer, shading

I've created my own beamer theme which uses a vertical shading for the background, but whenever I'm using a plain frame a thin white strip is left at the top of the page.

I've created a minimum working example that shows the problem even with the default beamer theme:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red,top=red]

\begin{document}
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know a solution to this?

Btw, I'm using beamer version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me with *"Beamer 2010/06/21 development version 3.10"*. This seems to be an bug which got fixed in the current version. Note that `beamer` uses `PGF` which should also be updated.

I used to have the exact same issue until I updated `beamer` and PGF.

Comment: Thanks, I've already suspected something like this. I installed the newest version in my personal texmf tree and the problem is gone!